# React and fetch requests

Tags: reactjs

I have this component which is wired up to a custom hook. Being new to this stuff my best guess is it has to do with useCallback somwhere (or lack thereof) but it's confusing the bejesus out of me because the request for picks never does it. When this gets sent to the Picks component it maps over the picks and the scores to render them. But loadedScores throws a cannot read properties of null error on page reload. To my knowledge that has something to do with the promise not being resolved yet, but if I hard code the score values, the loadedPicks object sends perfectly fine every time no matter how many times I reload the page. Why are the scores passing null but not the picks? Aren't both requests doing the exact same thing? Everything here works absolutely how I want it to as shown with the scores hard coded, but as soon as I try to use the values from the request it blows up.

Here's the main component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

import useHttp from "../hooks/use-http";
import { getScores } from "../lib/api";
import { getPicks } from "../lib/api";
import Picks from "./Picks";

const UserPicks = () => {
  const { sendRequest: scoreRequest, data: loadedScores } = useHttp(getScores);
  const {
    sendRequest: pickRequest,
    status,
    data: loadedPicks,
    error,
  } = useHttp(getPicks, true);

  useEffect(() => {
    pickRequest();
    scoreRequest();
  }, [pickRequest, scoreRequest]);

  if (status === "pending") {
    return <div>Loading games...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <p>{error}</p>;
  }

  if (status === "completed" && (!loadedPicks || loadedPicks.length === 0)) {
    return <div>No Games Found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Picks picks={loadedPicks} scores={loadedScores} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserPicks;
```

the hook:

```
import { useReducer, useCallback } from "react";

function httpReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === "SEND") {
    return {
      data: null,
      error: null,
      status: "pending",
    };
  }

  if (action.type === "SUCCESS") {
    return {
      data: action.responseData,
      error: null,
      status: "completed",
    };
  }

  if (action.type === "ERROR") {
    return {
      data: null,
      error: action.errorMessage,
      status: "completed",
    };
  }

  return state;
}

function useHttp(requestFunction, startWithPending = false) {
  const [httpState, dispatch] = useReducer(httpReducer, {
    status: startWithPending ? "pending" : null,
    data: null,
    error: null,
  });

  const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async function (requestData) {
      dispatch({ type: "SEND" });
      try {
        const responseData = await requestFunction(requestData);
        dispatch({ type: "SUCCESS", responseData });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: "ERROR",
          errorMessage: error.message || "Something went wrong!",
        });
      }
    },
    [requestFunction]
  );

  return {
    sendRequest,
    ...httpState,
  };
}

export default useHttp;
```

the request file:

```
const liveUrl = "https://nfl-schedule.p.rapidapi.com/v1/schedules";
const fireUrl =
  "https://office-pool-bc15f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/games.json";
const headers = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "nfl-schedule.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "35cba34c56msh4bdc15a4ca34516p11f9f6jsnb3c53161c895",
  },
};

export async function getGames() {
  const response = await fetch(liveUrl, headers);
  const data = await response.json();
  const games = data.data;

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Cannot retrieve games");
  }

  const currentGames = [];
  console.log(games);
  const days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];

  for (const game in games) {
    currentGames.push({
      key: games[game].shortName,
      id: games[game].shortName,
      name: games[game].name,
      visitor: games[game].awayTeam.name,
      host: games[game].homeTeam.name,
      date:
        days[new Date(games[game].date).getDay()] +
        " " +
        new Date(games[game].date).toLocaleDateString() +
        " " +
        new Date(games[game].date).toLocaleTimeString([], {
          timeStyle: "short",
        }),
    });
  }

  return currentGames;
}

export async function getScores() {
  const response = await fetch(liveUrl, headers);
  const data = await response.json();
  const scores = data.data;

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Cannot retrieve games");
  }

  const currentScores = [];
  console.log(currentScores);
  for (const score in scores) {
    currentScores.push({
      homeScore: scores[score].homeTeam.score,
      awayScore: scores[score].awayTeam.score,
    });
  }
  return currentScores;
}

export async function getPicks() {
  const response = await fetch(fireUrl);
  const data = await response.json();

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Cannot retrieve games");
  }

  const currentPicks = [];

  for (const game in data) {
    currentPicks.push({
      games: data[game].games,
      picks: data[game].picks,
      user: data[game].user,
    });
  }
  console.log(currentPicks);
  return currentPicks;
}
```

Comment: This is because even thought you are fetching data from picks and scores, you are only checking the status of the picks, and never the scores. The fetches are asynchronous and you are presenting a race condition: if picks is resolved earlier than scores, then you will attempt to use both data to render your component. But at this point scores are still undefined.

Comment: I thought of that before posting but it seems as though I did not validate the scores properly. Took me some time to get that but it works now, thank you.

Comment: Now let's say I want to run the score request periodically, every 5 minutes or so, or whatever, to update the score of each game, which would update the render to reflect if the user's pick is currently correct or not. Would I remove it from the useEffect and call it in an interval? It's hard for me to really test it without live games taking place. I'll figure it out once they start but I was hoping to have this live before then.